# Kotlin - Define variable globally for WebView

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I'm trying to define a variable globally which is of the class WebView. In Android Java it could be easy done by writing the it

Java for global variable

```
 < ClassName > < variableName >
```

But in Kotlin I'm facing issue with its declaration.

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var mywebview : WebView //<- This shows Property must be initialized or be abstract



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    mywebview = findViewById(R.id.webViewGyrix) as WebView

    mywebview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url);
            return true
        }
    } )
    mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/")
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This shows Property must be initialized or be abstract

Then initialize it i.e. to `null`. This is not a final value and you will be able to change it later:

```
var mywebview : WebView? = null
```

Alternatively, you can use [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) feature of Kotlin, which would let you prevent having nullable `mywebview` if not needed:

```
lateinit var webView: WebView
```

Comment: it shows: Null can not be a value of a non-null type WebView

Comment: Why cant we use lateinit here?

Answer (score 30):

You can use late initialization - you don't have to make WebView nullable

```
lateinit var webView: WebView
```

Comment: This is much better than accepted answer. Just don't access it before assigning it.

Comment: @RobCo it says Expecting member declaration

Comment: Also, This shows Property must be initialized or be abstract

Answer (score 0):

for a global variable, this means it shouldn't be overridden accidentally , so you should instead lazyload it using kotlin's lazy which create the variable on the first call, other calls will just reference the lazy loaded variable

```
private val webview:WebView by lazy{
  findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
}
```

That should come before the onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
val mywebviewURL = "https://www.google.com"

  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    events_webview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url);
            return true
        }
    })
    events_webview.loadUrl(mywebviewURL)
}
```

Add internet permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```